# Ember loading template multiple times and error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got an issue where it looks like Ember (1.6.0-beta.4) is attempting to load the same view a second time instead of transitioning to a different view.

The app has a login view and then the main page view.  The login view loads great.  No issues there.  The user enters their creds and hits login.  When a successful response comes back, the app transitions to the main page (route is updated as it should be).

But rather than rendering the main page, it renders the login page and the main page stacked together.  In the console, there's an error: "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: userName"

The only view that has an element with an id of 'userName' is the login view, which leads me to believe it is trying to render the login page a second time, (which is not what I want).

Ember inspector doesn't show anything out of place.  When I refresh the main page, the error goes away.

Here are the relevant parts of my app (copied and pasted from a series of js files, I tried to keep things organized as best i could)

my templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#if loggedIn}}
        <nav>
            <img id="navLogo" src="images/ExsellsiorMAnagerLogo.png" />
            <!--<div class="pull-right">Hello {{FirstName}}!</div>-->
        </nav>
        {{outlet}}
    {{else}}
        {{outlet}}
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="manifests">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            {{render 'filter' model}}
            <div id="library" class="col-md-3 left-column"><h2>Library</h2></div>
            <div id="stage" class="col-md-7 bg-danger"><h2>Stage</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <form id="login-form" role="form" class="form-horizontal" {{action login on="submit"}}>
            <div class="form-group">
                <img src="images/ExsellsiorMAnagerLogo.png" alt="Exsellsior Manager Logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userName" class="control-label hidden">User Name</label>
                {{input id="userName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" value=userName }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd" class="control-label hidden">Password</label>
                {{input id="pwd" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value=password}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{#if inProcess}}
                    <button id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-primary has-spinner spinner-active" type="submit">
                         Login<span class="spinner"><i class="icon-primary-spinner"></i></span>
                    </button>
                {{else}}
                     <button id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-primary has-spinner" type="submit">
                          Login<span class="spinner"><i class="icon-primary-spinner"></i></span>
                     </button>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
            {{#if invalidLogin}}
                 <div id="failure-message" class="form-group has-error bg-danger">
                     <span class="text-danger">Invalid username or password</span>
                 </div>
            {{/if}}
         </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

controllers:

```
app.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['login'],
    loggedIn: false,
    tokenChanged: function() {
        var self = this,
            login = self.get('controllers.login');

        if (login.get('token')) {
            this.set('loggedIn', true)
        } else {
            this.set('loggedIn', false)
        }
    },
    userInfoChanged: function () {
        var self = this,
            login = self.get('controllers.login');

        if (login.get('userInfo')) {
            this.setProperties(login.get('userInfo'));
        }
    },
    setState: function () {
        var self = this;
        var login = self.get('controllers.login');

        login.addObserver('token', self, self.tokenChanged);
        login.addObserver('userInfo', self, self.userInfoChanged);

        if (login.get('token')) {
            this.set('loggedIn', true);
            this.setProperties(login.get('userInfo'));
            this.transitionToRoute('manifests');
        } else {
            this.set('loggedIn', false);
            this.transitionToRoute('login');
        }
    }
});

app.LoginController = Em.Controller.extend({

    // resets login info so previous info is not stored
    reset: function () {
        var self = this;

        self.setProperties({
            userName: "",
            password: "",
            invalidLogin: false
        });
    },

    // define dependency on application controller
    //needs: ['application'],

    // initializes with user token, if one exists
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),

    userInfo: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo")),

    // monitors if token changes and updates local storage if so
    tokenChanged: function() {
        localStorage.setItem("token", this.get('token'));
    }.observes('token'),

    userInfoChanged: function () {
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(this.get('userInfo')))
    }.observes('userInfo'),

    actions: {
        // action to fire when user attempts to log in
        login: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (self.get('inProcess')) {
                return;
            }

            self.set('inProcess', true);

            // function.bind() specifies the context the function will be executed in
            //   (the 'this' object within the function)
            // login returns the promise from an AJAX call
            return app.util.login(self.get('userName'), self.get('password'))
                .then(loginSuccess.bind(self), loginFailure.bind(self));
        }
    }
});

app.FilterController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    showing: true,
    actions: {
        collapse: function () {
            this.set('showing', !this.get('showing'));
        }
    }
});
```

Routes:

```
app.Router.map(function () {
    // /login
    this.resource('login');

    // /manifests
    this.resource('manifests',function(){
        this.resource('filter');
    });
});

app.AuthenticatedRoute = Em.Route.extend({

    // checks if we have a token - if not we can assume we're
    //   not logged in before we make an ajax call
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        if (!this.controllerFor('login').get('token')) {
            this.redirectToLogin(transition);
        }
    },

    // function to handle re-routing to login screen
    redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
        var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
        loginController.set('attemptedTransition', transition);
        this.transitionTo('login');
    },

    // reusable function for data requests
    executeAjax: function(method, url, data) {
        var token = this.controllerFor('login').get('token');

        return app.util.executeAjax(method, url, token, data);
    },

    actions: {
        error: function(reason, transition) {
            if (reason.status === 401) {
                this.redirectToLogin(transition);
            } else {
                // todo: handle this better
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }
        }
    }
});

app.LoginRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    // ensures user data is cleared when login page loads/reloads
    setupController: function(controller, context) {
        controller.reset();
    }
});

app.ManifestsRoute = app.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.executeAjax("GET", "states").then(function (result) {
            return {
                states: result
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments can't be used in handlebars like this,

```
<!--<div class="pull-right">Hello {{FirstName}}!</div>-->
```

They should be wrapped in handlebars:

```
{{!-- foo --}}
```

Also your outlet should be out of the scope of the if statement:

```
{{#if loggedIn}}
    <nav>
        <img id="navLogo" src="images/ExsellsiorMAnagerLogo.png" />
        {{!-- <div class="pull-right">Hello {{FirstName}}!</div> --}}
    </nav>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```